# Bots status changes to <itertools.cycle object at 0x03EA9488>

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get my bot to change it's discord status automatically, yet it changes to `<itertools.cycle object at 0x03EA9488>`

This is all in a cog, and without the status changing code it works perfectly fine. I get no sorts of errors.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle

status = cycle(['status 1', 'status 2', 'status 3'])

class OnReady(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def change_status(self):
        await self.client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game(status))

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        self.change_status.start()
        print('Bot is online.')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(OnReady(client))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes.  You set the status variable to

```
cycle(['status 1', 'status 2', 'status 3'])
```

which is an

```
itertools.cycle object
```

just like it says.  A cycle is an infinite iterable object that works like so:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> c = itertools.cycle([1, 2, 3])
>>> next(c)
1
>>> next(c)
2
>>> next(c)
3
>>> next(c)
1
```

I don't know what `discord.Game` is, but inferring from context you probably want to change `activity = discord.Game(status)`, which calls `discord.Game` with the entire cycle as a parameter, to `activity = discord.Game(next(status))`.